# The client xxx with object id xxx does not have authorization to perform action Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over scope

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create a Resource Group dynamically using Azure Management SDK
Here are my azure configuration details

```
subscription=<private-data>
client=<private-data>
key=<private-data>
tenant=<private-data>
managementURI=https://management.core.windows.net/
baseURL=https://management.azure.com/
authURL=https://login.windows.net/
graphURL=https://graph.windows.net/
```

Here is code for creating Resource

```
// Credentials
AzureCredentials credentials = new AzureCredentialsFactory()
    .FromFile("azureauth.properties");
string resourceName = GetRandomString();

// Create Azure Instance
var azure = Azure
        .Configure()
        .Authenticate(credentials)
        .WithDefaultSubscription();

// Create a Resource Group
azure.ResourceGroups
        .Define(resourceName)
        .WithRegion(Region.USWest)
        .Create();
```

The error that I got is:

> The client 'ae8bc2ea-9680-4f66-934c-ad40b82c30ac' with object id
>   'ae8bc2ea-9680-4f66-934c-ad40b82c30ac' does not have authorization to
>   perform action
>   'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over scope
>   '/subscriptions/e9d61100-a82a-48ca-b6f8-51b06a1eebe6/resourcegroups/5oxjhjic'.

I have followed steps specified on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal
As well as I am trying with my **Global Administrator** account

Comment: So you created a service principal, what permissions did you give it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you cant be trying with global administrator, obviously. you need to go to you subscription and grant objectid 'ae8bc2ea-9680-4f66-934c-ad40b82c30ac' contributor permissions (easy way) or create a custom role (or figure predefined role) that meets your needs.

you can use portal to do that or azure powershell:

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId 'ae8bc2ea-9680-4f66-934c-ad40b82c30ac' -Scope '/subscriptions/e9d61100-a82a-48ca-b6f8-51b06a1eebe6' -RoleDefinitionName contributor
```

the equivalent Azure CLI command is:

```
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id ae8bc2ea-9680-4f66-934c-ad40b82c30ac --scope subscriptions/e9d61100-a82a-48ca-b6f8-51b06a1eebe6 --role contributor
```