# Client does not have authorization to add role using az role assignment create command when run in VSTS

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, command-line-interface, azure-pipelines

I added Azure CLI task in the VSTS pipeline and run 'az role assignment create' command to add role.

CLI command :

```
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id d7ad33ae-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-615f69e01ff3 --role "Storage Blob Data Reader" --scope /subscriptions/4364666b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-47158904c439/resourceGroups/devt002RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/devt002
```

Error :

```
2019-03-29T06:03:39.5026941Z ERROR: The client '82df9caa-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-12f72e07fe6d' with object id '82df9caa-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-12f72e07fe6d' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/4364666b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-47158904c439/resourceGroups/devt002RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/devt002/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/0c838340-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ec5190d4ef7a'.
2019-03-29T06:03:41.2266352Z ##[error]Script failed with error: Error: D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1553839394977.bat failed with return code: 1
```

**Note** : Using agent Hosted VS2017 and Azure CLI Task version 1.

It is running fine from my local command prompt.

Can anyone explain me from where this client id '82df9caa-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-12f72e07fe6d' is coming in the error message?

Comment: Have you tried use **azure powershell** task to do that, like: `New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId 'ae8bc2ea-9680-4f66-934c-ad40b82c30ac' -Scope '/subscriptions/e9d61100-a82a-48ca-b6f8-51b06a1eebe6' -RoleDefinitionName contributor`. If possible, check this thread for some more details:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350366/the-client-xxx-with-object-id-xxx-does-not-have-authorization-to-perform-action

Comment: yes tried that too. Same error. Even this one is not working from my local powershell prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give owner permission to the subscription before run CLI task in VSTS :
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id 82df9caa-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-12f72e07fe6d --role "owner" --scope /subscriptions/4364666b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-47158904c439

Now run the CLI task step :
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id d7ad33ae-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-615f69e01ff3 --role "Storage Blob Data Reader" --scope /subscriptions/4364666b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-47158904c439/resourceGroups/devt002RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/devt002