# How to authorize azure container registry requests from .NET CORE C#

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-container-registry

I have a web application which creates ContainerInstances, I have specific container registry images I want to use. As a result, I use this code to get my azure container registry

```
IAzure azure = Azure.Authenticate($"{applicationDirectory}/Resources/my.azureauth").WithDefaultSubscription();
IRegistry azureRegistry = azure.ContainerRegistries.GetByResourceGroup("testResourceGroup", "testContainerRegistryName");
```

I get this error when the second line of code is hit

```
The client 'bc8fd78c-2b1b-4596-827e-6a3c918b7c17' with object id 'bc8fd78c-2b1b-4596-827e-6a3c918b7c17' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/read' over scope '/subscriptions/506b787d-83ef-426a-b7b8-7bfcdd475855/resourceGroups/testapp-live/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/testapp' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

I literally have no idea what to do about this. I have seen so many articles talking about Azure AD and giving user roles and stuff. Can someone please walk me step by step how to fix this? I REALLY appreciate the help. Thanks.

I cannot find any client under that object ID so perfectly fine starting from scratch again with a better understanding of what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

The error usually occurs if you don't have **proper permissions** or **required role** to perform the action.

You can find the **`ObjectId`** and **`ClientId`** of your application like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active directory -> App registrations -> Your application -> Overview***

[image]

Assign **"Reader"** or **"Contributor"** role for your Azure Container Registry like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Container Registry -> Your Container Registry -> Access Control(IAM)***

[image]

After clicking Add role, select the **"Reader"** or **"Contributor"** role by searching them and assign required scope.

If the above doesn't work, try granting objectid `bc8fd78c-2b1b-4596-827e-6a3c918b7c17` **"Contributor"** permissions by using below command in Azure CLI:

```sh
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id bc8fd78c-2b1b-4596-827e-6a3c918b7c17 --scope /subscriptions/506b787d-83ef-426a-b7b8-7bfcdd475855/resourceGroups/testapp --role contributor
```

**Reference**:

[Authenticate with service principal - Azure Container Registry | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal)

[azure - The client xxx with object id xxx does not have authorization to performaction Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over scope - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350366/the-client-xxx-with-object-id-xxx-does-not-have-authorization-to-perform-action?rq=1)